# Your lawyer will broker a meeting.

Tags: word-usage

Is the usage of "broker" correct in the following sentence?

Your lawyer will broker a meeting between you and the defendant's car insurance company.

Comment: I believe that to be idiomatic.

Comment: English permits [use of nouns as verbs](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/), and vice-versa.

Comment: You need to be doing a little research on your questions.

Comment: I think the verb "broker" emphasizes the fact that it was not easy to arrange a meeting. He might have called more and spent more time than necessary to arrange a meeting between parties.

Comment: @Rathony +1 - At last a voice of sanity.  That actually makes sense.

Comment: Elaine - As you can see there has been some discussion about this. I believe that rajah9 has now answered it correctly. So:-  Did you write the sentence? If so what did you intend it to mean?  If someone else wrote it then we need more context to say whether the usage is correct.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Your comment is absolutely to the point. There is no particular reason to use "broker" instead of "arrange/set up/etc." unless the context requires it.

Answer (score 3):

As a noun, [broker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broker) means

> one who acts as an intermediary

In its verb form, it would mean one "to act as an intermediary."

In the sentence of the OP, it means that the lawyer will act as an intermediary between you and the defendant's car insurance company in setting up a meeting.

The primary sense is that the lawyer is setting up a meeting (perhaps a meeting place and time) for the two parties.

A secondary sense may include the idea that the lawyer is helping you and the insurance company to negotiate, but in that case the sentence might be better written:

> Your lawyer will broker a settlement between you and the defendant's car insurance company.

If it is the latter, then the lawyer is acting as a [business broker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_broker) and representing you (as opposed to being a disinterested third party).

Comment: +1    This makes sense to me and therefore I shall delete my answer. We now need to ask the OP what the sentence was *supposed* to mean.

Comment: Good point, but please retain your answer. Your interpretation points to the ambiguity in the OP sentence. If the lawyer is negotiating a meeting, it might be as providing a meeting room at his law firm. If the lawyer is brokering a settlement, he's not a disinterested party, and is will expect a percentage of the settlement.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I agree with rajah9. You don't need to delete your answer. I agree with this answer +1.

Answer (score 2):

'to broker' is a verb as can  be seen in the following dictionary definition:

> **broker**
>
> verb [T] UK    /ˈbrəʊ.kər/  US    /ˈbroʊ.kɚ/
>     to ​arrange something such as a ​deal, ​agreement, etc. between two or more
>   ​groups or ​countries:
>   The ​diplomats have ​failed in ​their ​attempts to broker a ​ceasefire.     [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/broker)

I would say that the use in your sentence is stretching this meaning.

(a) The  lawyer could **arrange a meeting** between you and the defendant's car-insurance company.

or

(b) Your lawyer could **broker a deal** between you and the defendant's car-insurance company.

Does 'broker a meeting' mean the first or the second or does it have a third meaning? I'm not sure.

**Updates**

1. In a comment Rathony says "I think the verb "broker" emphasizes the fact that it was not easy to arrange a meeting."

That makes sense.

2. Rajah9 has now formalised the third possible meaning and I agree with that answer.

Comment: The meaning is quite clear. It's more suitable than *arrange*, in my view, because it emphasize the idea of negotiation between parties to bring about a result. In fact, *negotiate* is probably its closest synonym.

Comment: If it is clear then which of the two does it mean? Please see my two options and my final sentence.

Comment: If Americans can say "I will overnight" and "Let's do lunch" they probably say "I will broker a meeting..."

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It is not only Americans who verb nouns. Check your Shakespeare.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I would prefer to use "broker" with deal, but it could be used with meeting as well.

Comment: @Robusto how many native speakers do you know who speak in Early modern English, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That's not the question. The question is whether native speakers verb nouns. They do. All the time. All over the world.

Comment: @Robusto No the OP doesn't mention anything about verbing nouns. The OP asks if the sentence is correct, if their usage of "broker" is correct. It is, yet another proofreading question on this site.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - asking about a  single word in a sentence is not proof-reading.

Comment: @Robusto - You say. " it could be used with meeting as well". Well maybe it could. However, my question to you is, if you use it with 'meeting, what does it then mean? Does it mean version (a) or version (b) that I wrote out in my answer?  This is a straightforward question. If you know the answer, please tell me.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broker+a+meeting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroker%20a%20meeting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: There's no support for the idea that broker means it wasn't easy to arrange.  It's not supported in the sentence, nor in the definitions in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

> Your lawyer will broker a meeting between you and the defendant's car insurance company.

Frankly, I don't see any problems with this sentence or the word 'broker'. I think the verb fits the definition quite nicely:

> to broker: to **arrange the details** of a deal, plan etc so that **everyone can agree** to it

(Macmillan English Dictionary)

Sounds exactly what a lawyer would do in the context given.

Comment: Yes but  'to arrange the details of a deal/plan' is not the same as 'to arrange a *meeting*'  I think Rathony has explained it properly in the comments.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK But there's an "etc" in the definition, too. So "meeting" is possible. "Details" are implied. Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broker+_DET_+meeting&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroker%20_DET_%20meeting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I think it's possible that both meanings can apply to "broker."  On another note, I'm not sure broker can be used for whoever and whatever.  The word has historical usage that makes it seem like it's current usage is idiomatic.